# Using GetChanges in Sharepoint SiteData web service

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to use this code to get changes in a site collection. But i don't know how to get the databaseId.

```
            SiteData.SiteData siteData = new SiteData.SiteData();
            siteData.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            siteData.Url = "http://localhost:333/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx";
            string lastChangeID = String.Empty;
            string result = siteData.GetContent(SiteData.ObjectType.SiteCollection, "", "", "", false, false, ref lastChangeID);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(result);
            string startChangeId = string.Empty;
            string endChangeId = doc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes["ChangeId"].Value;
            bool moreChanges;
            string databaseId = "";
            string result2 = siteData.GetChanges(SiteData.ObjectType.SiteCollection, databaseId, ref startChangeId, ref endChangeId, 5, out moreChanges);
            MessageBox.Show(result2);
```

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**
This is the GetContent Result:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to have the ContentDatabaseId? Passing an empty string for databaseId in GetChanges should give you the correct result anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the database Id for calling "GetChanges" method on SiteCollection scope. I use "GetChangesEx" and it works well, this method returns similar information to "GetChanges". Check the protocol specification (PDF) to see the differences: [Site Data protocol specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313109%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Also, I think your problem with the "SoapServerException" is the same I had here: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379077/how-to-call-getchanges-method-from-sitedata-asmx-web-service-sharepoint-2010).

This code example is on the other question I mentioned, but I'll post it here for better readability:

```
SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient siteDataService = new SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient();
siteDataService.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("URL/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

String xmlInput = "<GetChanges>" + 
                  "<ObjectType>7</ObjectType>" + 
                  "<ContentDatabaseId/>" + 
                  "<StartChangeId>1;1;69b025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634439727021700000;47404</StartChangeId>" + 
                  "<EndChangeId>1;1;69b025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634441802456970000;47472</EndChangeId>" + 
                  "<RequestLoad>100</RequestLoad>" + 
                  "<GetMetadata>False</GetMetadata>" + 
                  "<IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>True</IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>" + 
                  "</GetChanges>";
String result = siteDataService.GetChangesEx(1, xmlInput);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I used GetChangesEx() instead of GetChanges() like you described and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the siteData.GetContent method again, this time with the ContentDatabase as ObjectType. The returning CAML should contain the ContentDatabaseId.

```
string s = siteData.GetContent(SiteData.ObjectType.ContentDatabase, "", "", "", false, false, ref lastChangeID);
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look at the result of GetContent()

Comment: @Moussa: I am sorry, I misread your original code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Edwin: When i execute this code nothing happens and the code that comes after it doesn't run. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @Moussa: I am sorry, I am stumped as well. You can always try to post your question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Edwin: the exception that i got when executing the code you gave to me is: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' have you any idea what that means?

Comment: @Edwin: I tried without the database id and i got 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' i am suspecting that the parameters are wrong. Can you check them please?

Comment: @Moussa: But how did you get the result from GetContent you posted earlier? You did not need databaseId for that. So what DO you need it for then?

Comment: @Edwin: Ok. It seems that i don't need the databaseId. On the other hand when i call getChanges() like this string result2 = siteData.GetChanges(SiteDataWebReference.ObjectType.SiteCollection, "", ref startChangeId, ref endChangeId, 15000, out moreChanges); i get 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'

Comment: @Moussa: does the 'SoapServerException' object have any details or innerException?

Comment: QEdwin: The innerException is null.